Karate reusable function throwing an error Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document
First of all thank you for your time to address my question.
I have created a reusable to validate whether text contains or not. In that I am passing locator/text.
It looks like this
* def I_Verify_Text_Contains_ =
  """function(expectedLocatorOrValue,actualValue) {
        var expectedText;
           if(driver.exists(expectedLocatorOrValue) == true){
              retry().waitFor(expectedLocatorOrValue)
              expectedText = driver.text(expectedLocatorOrValue).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
           }
           else{
              expectedText = expectedLocatorOrValue;
           }

           res = expectedText.includes(actualValue);
          try {
                if(res)
                {
                   karate.log('PN-FUNCTIONS: It contains ' + actualValue)
                }
                else
                {
                   karate.fail('PN-FUNCTION-ERROR: It does not ' + actualValue)
                }
              }
              catch(e) {
                   if(e.message.includes('Cannot read property')) {
                        karate.fail('ERROR :The element [locator :'+ expectedLocatorOrValue + '] cannot be found')
                   } else if(e.message.includes('ReferenceError')) { karate.fail('ERROR : '+actualValue+' is not defined') }
                   else{ karate.fail(e.message) }
              }
  }"""

In feature file usage is like
#Passing locator
 Then I_Verify_Text_Contains_(MyLocatorDefinedInJsonFile, "Actual text to compare")
Or
#Passing value
Then I_Verify_Text_Contains_("Expected Value as Text", "Actual text to compare")

I am getting below error
Then I_Verify_Text_Contains_Or_Not_(poPageTitle,'Title of the page')

javascript failed twice: {"value":{"error":"javascript error","message":"javascript error: {\"status\":12,\"value\":\"Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'Title of the page' is not a valid selector.\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.86)","stacktrace":"\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00834CC3+225091]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00764E11]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00609A7A]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0060DEB0]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0060FA76]\n\t(No symbol) [0x006765E2]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0065F55C]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00675CB0]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0065F2F6]\n\t(No symbol) [0x006379B9]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0063879D]\n\tsqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00CA9A63+4064547]\n\tsqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00CB106A+4094762]\n\tsqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00CAB968+4072488]\n\tsqlite3_dbdata_init [0x009AC9C9+930953]\n\t(No symbol) [0x007707E4]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0076AD08]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0076AE31]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0075CAA0]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x75A8FCC9+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C57C5E+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C57C2E+238]\n"}} 



sorry that looks too complicated for me :( - I would recommend writing a pure JS function that does all the work in the browser, injecting it and then using it to get the result in one call. similar to this example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/axe/README.md - that's all I can think of. if you work with someone who knows JS well, you should be able to get this done

@PeterThomas I have rewritten the function in JS but I am getting same error. Please help! Thank you!

@PeterThomas, As advised I have rewritten in JavaScript and it is working fine. Thanks for your valuable time and guidance.
